# how to popen xterm on osx from c++ application?

Tags: c++, c, macos, console, xterm

I do this:

```
popen("xterm -e ' some bash script ' ","r");
```

and it works fine if I launch my application from a terminal command line.
but if I double click in the finder to launch it (i.e. non terminal), the application runs, but the xterm doesn't appear.

(xterm is maybe not the right solution on osx, what I want to do is to open a terminal from popen, interact with the user inside the terminal, and return the result of this interaction to the main program)

Comment: What sort of application is it?  Command line or Cocoa?

Comment: it's a X11 application using glut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output shown in xterm's window (or likely other terminals) will not be read by `popen`, so that part is unclear.  However, you say that works from a terminal window.

Another problem is that the `DISPLAY` variable needed to run xterm may not be set in the environment where the finder is running.  You can work around *that* by adding a suitable `-display` option to the command-line.  For instance, if your application is running and displaying on the local machine (likely), you could try

```
popen("xterm -display :0.0 -e ' some bash script ' ","r");
```

When capturing output from xterm, there are two types of output to consider:

- error messages from xterm itself are written to the standard error
- the program running inside xterm, e.g., `'some bash script'`, will write to the xterm window.

For your example, you could capture the error messages in the pipe (from `popen` directly by redirecting the standard error in the command to xterm's standard output, e.g.,

```
popen("xterm -display :0.0 -e ' some bash script ' 2>&1 ","r");
```

Capturing the output of the bash script is harder.  You could redirect the output of the bash script itself, e.g.,

```
popen("xterm -display :0.0 -e ' some bash script >mylogfile ' ","r");
```

but that interferes with interaction.  A better solution might be to use the `script` program, doing something like this:

```
popen("xterm -display :0.0 -e  script mylogfile ' some bash script ' ","r");
```

Comment: the -display :0.0 doesn't change anything. And you are right, popen doesn't send thing back from the xterm, I will write a temp file to get things back. or maybe I can try to redirect the xterm output to popen &2.